# How do you query a table filtering on a substring of one of the columns?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table I wish to query. It has a string variable called comment which contains an ID along with other things. (i.e. "123456;varA;varB")

| rowNo | comment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "123456;varA;varB" |
| 2 | "987654;varA;varB" |

I want to filter based on the first substring in the comment variable.

That is, I want to filter the table on rows where the first substring of comment is "123456" (which in the example would return the first row)

How do I do this?

I was thinking something along the lines of the code below, using the "string_split" function, but  it doesn't work.

```
SELECT *,
FROM table
WHERE (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(comment,';',1)="123456")
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Note, I am querying in SQL in SAS, and this is on a large dataset, so I don't want to create a new table with a new column to then query on instead. Ideally I'd want to query on the existing table directly.

Comment: No need to split at all in this case. Can just do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE value like '"123456;%"'`

Comment: Are you stuck with the ; (semicolon) as delimiter? If not, you could use a comma and you can use find_in_set() function. Assuming MySQL.

Ideally its a horibbly inefficient way to store data, if you can re-factor it at all you could store this as a JSON column type and you can treat it almost like extra fields in the query as normal (almost), again assuming MySQL.

Comment: If you are using SAS then why the request for SQL code?   Are you pushing the query explicitly into some external database?  If so what database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SCAN() function to parse a string.

```
WHERE '123456'=scan(comment,1,';')
```